# iTunes Send Archive Failed, privacy-sensitive data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, itunes, xcode8

I'm trying to submit my app, but iTunes send me this email :

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.

But in the info.plist and the infoPlist.strings, I'm explain the usage description, see my screenshot.

[image: info.plist]

[image: infoPlist.strings]

I have also updated google analytics and google admob sdk.

So how to submit my app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after rename the Info.plist...
Certainly a bug with xCode 8...